# HTML5 Canvas: I'm trying to load an image to the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to setup a canvas where the user can load a custom image.
As far as I can tell everything should be set but for some reason it is not working.

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6um13rs/).

HTML:

```
<canvas id="image-canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<input type='file' id='fileInput' />
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Trigger the imageLoader function when a file has been selected
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader(), false);

function imageLoader() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      img = new Image();
      img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      }
      img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling imageLoader, not passing as a function to call.

Replace

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader(), false);
```

by

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, though Im afraid that even with the fix the image is still not loading.

Comment: @AGS I tested with your jsfiddle (modified), and it works for me.

Comment: Sorry, it's working now. There was a problem with the image I was trying to load. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One line is wrong. Here is the fixed line:

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader, false);
```